# Apt-get update always stuck at getting Release.gpg

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates

While I run apt-get update on Ubuntu 12.04, I got the following output (partially):

```
Get:1985 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [28.9 kB]
...
```

My sources.list file is not modified and I use the main server as the repository.

I tried to remove /var/lib/apt/lists/* and update again but failed.

I retrieved the Release.gpg file manually: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg

Found that the file size is 198 instead of 28.9kB, any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem on Debian using simple-cdd.  I resolved the issue by specifying the version using --dist wheezy.

Comment: Welcome to ask-ubuntu and thank you for your answer. Unfortunatelly it is rather incomplete and may be misleading. With which program did you use `--dist wheezy`? `apt-get` does not have this option and the original question has nothing to do with `simple-cdd`.